# How can I assign a Start value to a Stepper in Swift when using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistepper

I'm quite new to Swift and developing my first app.

I want to assign a start value to a UIStepper through code so that I can automate/randomize it.

Using something like `self.MyStepper.value` in the `viewDidLoad` func failed.

I also have tried using `MyStepper.value = 5` in the stepper func but I got this error message:

> Value of type '(UIStepper) -> ()' has no member 'value'

My code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ConceptViewController: UIViewController {

    //Organisation
    var StartOrg: Int = 5
    @IBOutlet weak var OrgPercentLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var OrgCashLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var StepperOrgOut: UIStepper!
    
    @IBAction func StepperOrg(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        OrgCashLabel.text = String((sender.value)*50) + "€"
        OrgPercentLabel.text = String((sender.value)*10) + "%"
    }
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        self.OrgCashLabel.text = String(StartOrg*50) + "%"
        self.OrgPercentLabel.text = String(StartOrg*10) + "€"
        self.TeamCashLabel.text = String(StartTeam*50) + "%"
        self.TeamPercentLabel.text = String(StartTeam*10) + "€"
    }
```

Comment: it's difficult to help you if you don't post your code.

Comment: maybe you want to check this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: Posted the code and the link did not help me :/.

I also have tried using MyStepper.value = 5 in the Stepper func but I got this error message: Value of type '(UIStepper) -> ()' has no member 'value'

Comment: according to your code, your UIStepper variable is called `StepperOrgOut`. Hence you'd be addressing it by this name when you want to change the value, for instance: `StepperOrgOut.value = 5`

Comment: FYI - It is standard practice to name variables, functions, and case names starting with a lowercase letter. Class, struct, and enum names start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some issues in your code:

1. In `viewDidLoad`:
   Instead of the stepper's outlet, you might have set the ".value" attribute to your StepperVC's IBAction.
2. Only when the value of stepper changes via UI, IBAction of stepper called (in the Storyboard Screen).
3. IBAction won't be invoked whenever the stepper's value is altered by code.
   IBAction for that stepper must be manually called.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var StepperOrgOut: UIStepper!

@IBAction func StepperOrg(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    OrgCashLabel.text = String((sender.value)*50) + "€"
    OrgPercentLabel.text = String((sender.value)*10) + "%"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.StepperOrgOut.value = StartOrg // stepper set

    StepperOrg(StepperOrgOut)           // IBAction call

    //This 2 line not to set manually if you call IBAction 
    //self.OrgCashLabel.text = String(StartOrg*50) + "%"
    //self.OrgPercentLabel.text = String(StartOrg*10) + "€"


    self.TeamCashLabel.text = String(StartTeam*50) + "%"
    self.TeamPercentLabel.text = String(StartTeam*10) + "€"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```swift
import UIKit

class StepperVC: UIViewController {
  //Make outlets for label and stepper    
  @IBOutlet weak var lblStepper: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
  //Make a IBAction for stepper       
  @IBAction func btnValueChangeStepper(_ sender: Any) {
    lblStepper.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"
  }
}
```

[Here is link to guide you step by step](https://sourcefreeze.com/uistepper-example-in-swift/)